# How to structure such data

Tags: data-structures

How structure data storing single Integer and List of Integers. Take leetcode 341 as an example, it gives an instance of nestedinteger interface and says do not speculate about its implementation. My question is how to implement such data structure?

Comment: What you've done so far, add your code here to get better chance of help

Comment: As it's required from LC 341, it requires the data structure could store single integer and a list of integer. Apparently, this structure is a typical recursive definition. I think we could define as the following. Use Java's super parent class, Object to achieve. \n Define List<Object> lst, because Integer is a child class of Object, List is also a child of Object, thus, we could store single integer in lst as well as a list of integer in lst.  But this is use the original java class to mimic this structure without implementing the isInteger, isList, getInteger, getList methods.

Comment: If we use the same logic. I think we should define a superclass, let's called it Father, then, we should define two child class, one is Value that represents single integer. the other one is ValueList that stores the a list of Value. This is what appears in my mind. Is there any better way to achieve this?